# How to Remove 「Total」 row in SSRS report?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am new to SSRS.

In report, I have One table layout result where its first row (there is a bug in total) and last row is having total of all the fields. (Like shown in below image)

[image]

Given 「Total」 in first row, which I want to remove from the Report simply. I have its source file and I tried already so many ways but I am not getting its solution.

### Edited

Design View of the same is here

[image]

Row Groups Panel is looking like:

[image]

Group Properties:
[image]

Expression 1(top left most):

```
=Iif(Fields!LineCaption.Value="","TOTAL", Fields!DispOrder.Value & ". " & Fields!LineName.Value)
```

Expression 2(below of top left):

```
=Iif(Fields!LineCaption.Value="","　", Fields!AddupInfo.Value)+ "　"
```

Comment: Show the design of the report , not the preview!

Comment: @PrathapG: Yes, I have edited question. Please have a look

Comment: Can you post your grouping panels too, It's in the bottom panel

Comment: What are the properties of your group?

Comment: @Larnu: Edited the question for Group property. All other tabs are NULL or Unchecked

Comment: looks that is your totals group then, as I assumed "LineCode" and "Line Name" are synonyms? If you delete the group (and its related rows) that the group go away?

Comment: @Larnu: Yes True. If i delete the Group the group goes away and nothing is getting display. Also "LineCode" & "Line Name" are synonyms.

Comment: "nothing gets display", do mean the group? *Normally* there is a data group in the group section; the fact that is it missing suggests it's been deleted. If so, it'll probably be easier to reattach the dataset to the tablix.

Comment: @Larnu: I guess you are close to answer bcz your each suggestions and points are matching to my Actual source. And yes "Group is not getting display in Preview"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184862/discussion-between-im-one-and-larnu).

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: For a Workaround,  You can right click the required row and then go the Row visibility and then select Hide and then Click OK,  Design is already in he report. But once it run user no longer cannot see that row.  May be this will help you

Comment: @AnushaSubashini: Thank you for the comment but I already tried that way also. But it's not working!

Comment: What are the expressions used in the two <Expr> cells in the far left column?

Comment: @McGlothlin: Yes I have edited now in the question. please check

Comment: @jap_jap You are editing several questions of yours, removing links to images. Any particular reason? You are referring to them in your question text however. Make sure your questions still stand after removing these links please.

Comment: @TT.: There was having sensitive data in image!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you to All Commentators for commenting and giving your precious time in my problem with suggestions.

But I have found my own way solution.
By creating condition on Row_Group Visibility option while it loads the data from server.

As「`Total`」field was getting calculated in Row_Group only. So in Visibility option, I checked for first Row that "`If first row is not Line_Name(My field name) then Hide that Row`".
Maybe this is not the accurate answer but this was the only option for me to add.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via the context menu in the matrix view, not in the "Row Group" are:

[image]